# xml parsing after fetch function

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I am trying to print the some values of the xml below. The first three lines print the right text as I wanted. But the last line does not print anything. Am I missing something about parsing the xml?

```
foreach ($response->values as $value) {
print $value->updateType.' ';
print $value->updateContent->person->id.' ';
print $value->updateContent->person->firstName.' '.$value->updateContent->person->lastName;
print ':::'.$value->updateContent->person->connections->firstName.':::'; //FAIL
}


<update>
    <timestamp>1262628716000</timestamp>
    <update-type>CONN</update-type>
    <update-content>
        <person>
            <id>Sa_cgv2lRl</id>
            <first-name>John</first-name>
            <last-name>Irving</last-name>
            <headline>Author</headline>
            <connections total="1">
                <person>
        <id>B0Vweu0eVU</id>
        <first-name>Paul</first-name>
        <last-name>Auster</last-name>
        <headline>EWriter</headline>
        </person>
     </connections>
     </person>
 </update-content>
  </update>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously, it should be:

```
print $value->{'update-content'}->person->connections->person->{'first-name'};
```

see the `<person>` node after `<connections>`!

Moreover, there's a mismatch between your XML and your code, e.g. `updateContent` vs. `update-content`, `firstName` vs. `first-name`. In case of the latter, see the special syntax required to access nodes with a dash.